# How to get previous session id in java

Tags: java, session

I have a small java application. In which I wanted to store online users details. For that I have created a map and stored user details corresponding to sessionId. This will works fine. But my problem is how I know the users browser seession expires? I want to remove those users details from map whose sessiopn will no longer exists. Could you please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply register [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) and remove those users details from map whose sessiopn will no longer exists as suggested by @Scary Wombat

#### web.xml:

```
<web-app ...>
    <listener>
          <listener-class>com.x.y.z.MySessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

#### HttpSessionListener:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

public class MySessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("sessionCreated");
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("sessionDestroyed");  
        // e.getSession()  
        // remove users details from map
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html)

From the [HttpSessionEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionEvent.html) parameter you can get the actual session.